# How can I find a local/regional photography club?

Tags: clubs

Is there a good resource for listing local/regional photography clubs?

Comment: While we generally don't encourage questions that are specific to certain localities, I think that asking about how one might find such clubs seems relevant.

Answer (score 8):

One good resource would be to check with local retail camera stores - they're likely aware of (if not directly connected with) local photography clubs.

Another resource would be tracking down the local chapter of the pro photo organizations such as ASMP.

Answer (score 7):

One place you might find worth looking at is http://www.meetup.com. Of course, I can't make any guarantees about what (if anything) you'll find in your area, but it stands at least a decent chance of coming up with something.

Comment: +1 I became aware of quite a few groups which share my interests, including photography, just by browsing the Meetup site.

Answer (score 4):

Flickr has many regional groups with active participants. For example, I am a member of a bird photography group devoted to my city. Many members are willing to meetup and go on shoots together.

Answer (score 1):

We have an hobbyist photo club at work. We meet every other week during lunch break and have various activities during meeting, usually following a calendar set once or twice a year. The activities include topical assignments, member shows, tutorials and gallery displays in our cafeteria.

See if you have something running in your workplace, and if not, found one! You may be surprised at how many people there find interest in sharing and improving their photography skills.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly enough. Facebook.

I've joined several virtual clubs who have various physical meetups; such a shoots, tutorials, socials, even exhibitions.

Just have a search in the search bar for 'geographical area' photography, then refining the search to groups. These days I think search results tend to be ordered by locale as well so you may be able to omit the geographical area from your search and just rely on groups.

This method, but maybe searching pages as well as groups could result in some local physical ones to.

Answer (score -1):

[meetup.com](http://meetup.com) is perfect for this! It's how I found the photography group that I participate in.